# Getting empty response from python server , using the android 5,6 versions

Tags: android, python

Using the HttpURLConnection I send post requests from my android app to my python server , and **problem** is it works(gets normal, non empty response) only in android 4 version(it does not work in android 5, 6 versions), and the most interesting thing is server accepts requests from app, but app gets empty response . I can't understand why it happens. Below is my code. Sorry for bad eng:

HttpUrlConnection's code:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream());
out.print(param);
out.close();
String response = "";
Scanner inStream = new Scanner(con.getInputStream());
while (inStream.hasNextLine()) {
    response += (inStream.nextLine());
}
```

python server's function which returns response:

```
def send_response(res):
    bytes__ = str.encode(str('\n\n\n' + '{' + res + '}'))
    self.wfile.write(bytes__)
    return
```